# JQGrid - How Can I populate dropdownlist in searchoption from MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, jqgrid

I found this code for populate searchoption

```
editoptions: { value: "List:School" }, stype: 'select',
searchoptions: { value: "List:List Prices;School:School Prices" }
```

But I want to Populate it from Data in Controller use some JQuery Ajax like this

```
$.getJSON(url, function (data)
```

How can I do it.Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

Look at another [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4101116/asp-net-mvc-post-call-returning-string-need-help-with-format-for-jqgrid/4102155#4102155). The `dataUrl` and `buildSelect` parameter of the [searchoptions](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:search_config#colmodel_options) works exactly like the same parameter of the [editoptions](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:common_rules#editoptions). So you can use the same code.

If you want have different values and display names inside of drop-down list you can make a simple modification in the code from [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4101116/asp-net-mvc-post-call-returning-string-need-help-with-format-for-jqgrid/4102155#4102155). I hope it will be no problem you you.