# Problem with $.each in jquery

Tags: jquery, jqgrid

I am trying to populate a jqGrid search form using a SELECT element. In the colModel for the interested column I have

```
searchoptions: {
    dataUrl: '<%: Url.Content("~/Contact/GetCustomers") %>',
    buildSelect: function (response) {
        var theSelect = "<select>";
        $.each(response, function (i, data) {
            theSelect += '<option value="' + data.Value + '">' + data.Text + '</option';
        });
        theSelect += "</select>";
    },
    sopt: ['eq', 'ne']
}
```

the remote method GetCustomers return a json result formatted as

```
[{"Selected":false,"Text":"David Gilmour","Value":"10"},
 {"Selected":false,"Text":"Eric Clapton","Value":"26961"},
 {"Selected":false,"Text":"Joan Baetz","Value":"26972"}]
```

but with the code that I have used for the each function I am getting the following error

[image]

Comment: What is the value `response` being passed in?  Can you show us what it looks like in your debugger?

Comment: it says `[object XMLhttpRequest]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since (according to your comment above) you're getting the `XMLHttpRequest` object, you need to parse its response text.

```
var parsed = $.parseJSON( response.responseText );

$.each( parsed, function(...
```

Or modify the code that is passing the response to pass just the response text, or the parsed result.

Answer (score 1):

response is just a string it needs to be parsed using something like [json2.js](http://www.json.org/js.html)

```
var data = JSON.parse(response);
```

Answer (score 1):

Look at [the close answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4101116/asp-net-mvc-post-call-returning-string-need-help-with-format-for-jqgrid/4102155#4102155). It seems to me you should modify the code a little:

```
buildSelect: function(data) {
    var response = jQuery.parseJSON(data.responseText);
    var s = '<select>';
    if (response && response.length) {
        for (var i = 0, l=response.length; i<l ; i++) {
            var ri = response[i];
            s += '<option value="' + ri.Value +
                 (ri.Selected ? '" selected="selected">': '">') +
                 ri.Text + '</option>';
        }
   }
   return s + "</select>";
}
```

Comment: thans a lot. This will work as well. The problem was in using `parseJSON(response.responseText);` as indicated by @patrick_dw and even present in your answer. After that modification the `$.each` block in my code works fine and is more compact. Thanks a lot!

Comment: @Lorenzo: You welcome! The most important is that your problem is solved. To tell the truth I prefer to write answers to jqgrid and not on pure jQuery/jQuery UI questions because I write/type prity slow. :-)

Comment: I know what you mean. For me you are the maximum reference on jqGrid!! :)

Answer (score 0):

Are you parsing this JSON object so you can read it as an actual JS object proper?

Since you are returning an array of JSON objects, you might have to parse each object individually as you iterate.

Answer (score 0):

I would try using `$(this)` inside the each function. Though it looks right, something may be fishy with the result. Alternativly you could use a `for (var d in data)` (I think) for iterating over a JSON.