# JQGrid DataUrl usage with ASP.net (MVC 2.0)

Tags: jqgrid

I want to display a combobox with add/edit dialog on Jqgrid. I could do it with hardcoded values. But now I want to populate data from database (controller action). Can anyone help me writting the controller code for DataUrl. (Does it need Json formatted string of Value & Text?). My Grid definition is as below.

My other url actions are working fine.

```
        jQuery("#myGrid").jqGrid({
            pager: jQuery('#myGridPager'),
            sortname: 'Name',
            rowNum: 10,
            rowList: [10, 20, 50],
            sortorder: "asc",
            height: "auto",
            autowidth: true,
            colNames: ['Id', 'Name', 'Dept', 'Status', 'ParentNodeName'],
            colModel: [
              { name: 'Id', index: 'Id', hidden: true, key : true },
              { name: 'Name', index: 'Name', width: 200, editable: true, edittype: "text", editrules: { required: true} },
              { name: 'Dept', index: 'Dept', width: 90, editable: true, editrules: { required: true} },
              { name: 'Status', index: 'Status', width: 25, editable: true, edittype: "select", editoptions: { value: "A:Active;I:Inactive"} },
              { name: 'ParentNodeName',
                        index: 'ParentNodeName',
                        editable: true,
                        edittype: "select",
                        editoptions: { dataUrl: "/MyEntity/GetMyEntitys" }
                    },
              ], 
            datatype: 'json',
            viewrecords: true,
            mtype: 'GET',
            jsonReader: {
                root: "rows",
                page: "page",
                total: "total",
                records: "records",
                repeatitems: false,
                userdata: "userdata"
            },
            url: "/MyEntity/GetMyEntitysData",
            multiselect: false,
            editurl: "/MyEntity/EditMyEntity?__SESSIONKEY=<%=Model.SessionKey %>",
            caption: "Data Entry"
        })
        .navGrid('#myGridPager', { view: true, del: true, add: true, edit: true },
        { height: 150, reloadAfterSubmit: false, modal: true }, // default settings for edit
        { height: 150, reloadAfterSubmit: true, modal: true, url: "/MyEntity/AddMyEntity?__SESSIONKEY=<%=Model.SessionKey %>" }, //  settings for add
        { height: "auto", reloadAfterSubmit: false, modal: true, url: "/MyEntity/DeleteMyEntity?__SESSIONKEY=<%=Model.SessionKey %>" }, // delete 
        { closeOnEscape: true, multipleSearch: true, closeAfterSearch: true }, // search options
        {} /* view parameters*/
      );
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

jqGrid wait for HTML code fragment (a valid HTML `<select>` element with the desired `<options>`: `<select><option value='1'>One</option>…</select>`) as the data returned from the `dataUrl: "/MyEntity/GetMyEntitys"`. Because you return the data in JSON format you have to convert the data returned from the server with respect of the `editoptions` [buildSelect](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:common_rules#editoptions). You can see the corresponding code example in my [old answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4101116/asp-net-mvc-post-call-returning-string-need-help-with-format-for-jqgrid/4102155#4102155).

One more small remark. Look at [the jqGrid documentation](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:jqgriddocs) and verify which parameters which you use are default. For example `multiselect: false` is default parameter. If you remove the default parameters from the grid definition the code wil be easier to read and it will work a litle bit quickly. In more complex parameters like `jsonReader` you could include only the properties which you want to **change**. For example you can use `jsonReader` in the form `jsonReader : { repeatitems: true}` because `repeatitems` is the only property of `jsonReader` which you want to change from the default settings. In the same way you can reduce `{ view: true, del: true, add: true, edit: true }` to `{ view: true }`.

Answer (score 1):

Call controller code in dataUrl using edit options as below:

```
.aspx/js code:
```

editoptions: `{ dataUrl: "/YourControllerName/TheFunction" }`

The controller code here:

```
public string TheFunction()
        {
            return ConstructSelect(Model.YourList);
        }

        public string ConstructSelect(SelectList collection)
        {
            string result = "<select>";

            foreach (var item in collection)
            {
                result = result + "<option value = '" + item.Value + "'>" + item.Text + "</option>";
            }

            result = result + "</select>";
            return result;
        }
```

Comment: how does jqgrid know what to default the selected item to when you are updating an existing row ??