# Populate jqGrid dropdown using beforeShowForm Event

Tags: javascript, jqgrid

I'm trying to dynamically populate a dropdown when a user is trying to add a new record in a detail jqGrid.  Here's what I have so far.  It's pulling in the data fine but it just won't set the value to the dropdown.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
beforeShowForm: function(formid) {
       var sr = $("#list").jqGrid('selrow');
       if (sr) {
           // get data from master
           var UserID = $("#list").getGridParam('selrow');
           var roles = $.ajax({ type: "POST",
               url: '<%= ResolveUrl("~/Admin/GetRoles/") %>' + UserID,
               dataType: "json",
               async: false,
               success: function(data) {

               }
           }).responseText;

           // set the field in detail with the value of mnaster
           $("#UserID", formid).val(UserID);
  // try and populate dropdown
           $('#detail').setColProp('Description', { editoptions: { value: roles} });
       } else {
           // close the add dialog
           alert("no row is selected");
       }

   }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your [first question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4101116/asp-net-mvc-post-call-returning-string-need-help-with-format-for-jqgrid) I explained you how to use `dataUrl` to generate the contain of the dropdown list dynamically. If you use [form editing](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:form_editing) to modify the grid data you can use `beforeInitData` instead of `beforeShowForm` to modify the `dataUrl` to `'<%= ResolveUrl("~/Admin/GetRoles/") %>' + $("#list").jqGrid('selrow')` **before** the form will be filled. In the way you can simplify your code, make the `ajax` request asynchronous and the question with setting the values to the dropdown control will be solved automatically.

Comment: Thank you Oleg.  I will review this again.

Comment: Oleg -- the beforeInitData worked!  Thank you so much for your help!!

Comment: Oleg, I'm having performance issues in Internet Explorer 8 when the drop down contains > 300 items.  Any suggestions on this?

Comment: @dolphy: If you could post the full working example (including the corresponding JSON data just a text file) which reproduce the problem I could try to help you. I suppose that for the user the choice from so many items in the dropdown list could be also difficult. The usage of jQuery UI *autocomplete* widget (see http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/) could improve user experience.

Comment: Ok...so, instead of using a dropdown, I can bind a jQuery UI autocomplete to the text field in the jqGrid form edit?  I will try this out.  Good advice.

Comment: Ok.  I got the AutoComplete working in the edit form.  Thanks so much for your advice Oleg.  Your contributions to this are greatly appreciated!

Comment: @Oleg have you bind this dropdown with name/value pair? 
What should be the column names in order to bind dropdown with name/value pair?

Comment: @sohaiby: Sorry, but I don't understand your question. Which scenario you mean? Do you have *local*  object which you want to use as the source of information about the dropdown or you load the data from `dataUrl`? What kind of binding you mean? Do you mean event binding or just the usage of the data as the source of information (data binding in common understanding of it)? Which editing mode you use? `beforeShowForm` callback can be used in form editing only, but `dataInit` is more common. Which version of jqGrid/free jqGrid/Guriddo jqGrid JS you use? free jqGrid has `buildSelect` callback.