# Array (json) not passing into jqGrid's editoptions parameters

Tags: javascript, jquery, jqgrid

I've been trying to pass an array from a global variable (`codata`) to an option array of `editoptions` (jqGrid). My code stands as follows:

--------- countries_list.php throws the following json array -----------

```
["ABU","AD","AE","AF" .... "ZA","ZM","ZW"]
```

--------- PHP script with jqGrid Code ----------

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){

            var codata = new Array();

            $.getJSON('countries_list.php', function(list){
                $.each(list, function(val) {
                    codata.push("'"+val+"'");
                    # --- Here alert() displays 'codata' with all the elements ---
                });
            });

            $("#datatable").jqGrid({
                 ......
                 // some code until colMode specs
                 ......
                 {   name:'guco',
                        index:'guco',
                        edittype:'select',
                        width:90,
                        editable: true,
                        editoptions: {
                            formatter:'select',
                            value: codata # --- array is not passed, it comes empty ---
                        },
                        sortable: true,
                        resizable: false
                    },
        .....
```

--------- PHP script with jqGrid Code ----------

Any hint how to get this fixed?, thanx in advance.

Mario Benitez.-

Answer (score 2):

Thanx a lot to all you guys, I learnt a lot with your contributions. Problem was fixed as follows:

(reading about) I found that getjson works an 'async mode' (I'm a jQuery newbie) and the code to fix the problem was:

```
    jQuery(document).ready(function(){

        var codata = (function () {
            var list = null;

            $.ajax({
                'async': false,
                'global': false,
                'url': 'countries_list.php',
                'dataType': 'json',
                'success': function (data) {
                    list = data;
                }
            });

            return list;
        })();

        $("#datatable").jqGrid({
             ... jqGrid settings ...
            colModel: [
                ....
                {   name:'guco',
                    index:'guco',
                    edittype:'select',
                    width:90,
                    editable: true,
                    editoptions: {
                        value: codata
                    },
                    sortable: true,
                    resizable: false
                },
                ....
```

Thanx a lot once again, I hope this helps to someone else.

Mario Benitez.

Answer (score 0):

From what i see your php script is passing valid js array, not json object. The most logic thing to do is to call jqGrid inside the ajax callback assigning `$("#datatable").jqGrid({ ... editoptions: { value: list } ... });`

Comment: Async operation might result in problems to store data in the array

Comment: In fact because it's async `codata` is undefined the time you refer to it and that's callbacks for.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend you to use `dataUrl` together with `buildSelect` instead of `value` of the `editoptions`. You can find the corresponding code example of `buildSelect` in the "UPDATED" part of [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4101116/asp-net-mvc-post-call-returning-string-need-help-with-format-for-jqgrid/4102155#4102155).

Comment: I'll keep 'the answer' link because I'll need in the near future. I'll post the solution.

Answer (score 0):

I tried both ways and the Answer given in Olegs links helped.  Using the buildSelect param allows full control of the value.  When I used value method it assigned simple integer values of 0 - n.  You can also assign your own CSS classes in this paradigm too.  +1 for buildSelect/dataurl.