# jqGrid Dynamic dropdownlist

Tags: jqgrid, drop-down-menu

I am new to jqGrid, and having trouble with achieving a couple of tasks. Any guidance will be a huge help.

I need to have dynamically populated drop down list.

```
 $("#HEALTH_PLAN_CATEGORY_VALUE_ID").change(function () {            $.getJSON('/Ajax/GetCountyForHealthPlan', { id: $(this).val() }, function (counties) {                var ddlSelectedCounty = $("#COUNTY_GSA_LOOKUP_ID");

                // clear all previous options                $("#COUNTY_GSA_LOOKUP_ID > option").remove();

                // populate the products                for (i = 0; i < counties.length; i++) {

                    ddlSelectedCounty.append($("<option />").val(counties[i].Value).text(counties[i].Text));                }

            });

        });
```

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need to fill options in the select list of edit form for some column dynamically you should use `dataUrl` to get the data from the server and `buildSelect` to convert the server response to `<select><option value='val'>Text</option>...</select>`. See "UPDATED" part of [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4102155/315935) for an example.