# jqgrid colmodel editoptions to load json result

Tags: jqgrid

I want to load my server data in the DropDown of my jqgrid. My code,

UPDATED CODE:

```
 public ActionResult GetUnit()
    {
        List<UnitModel> getUnitValues = new List<UnitModel>();
        //ToDo db code
        Dictionary<int, string> unitValues = new Dictionary<int, string>();
        unitValues = getUnitValues.ToDictionary(x => x.UnitID, x => x.UnitDesc);
        unitValues.Add(4, "Unit2/3");
        unitValues.Add(1, "Unit1");
        unitValues.Add(2, "Unit2");
        unitValues.Add(3, "Unit3");
        return Json(unitValues, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

My jqgrid:

```
     colModel: [...
      {
            name: 'UnitID', index: 'UnitID', editable: true, edittype: 'select', width: "200",
            formatter: 'select', editoptions: { value: unitslist},
            editrules: { custom: true, custom_func: dupicateRecordValidation
            }
        },
...],

       beforeProcessing: function () {
                    $.ajax({
                    url: '/Home/GetUnit/',
                    dataType: 'json',
                    type: 'POST',
                    contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
                    success: function (data) {
                        $.map(data, function (value, key) {
                            unitsList += '"' + value + '"' + ':' + '"' + key + '"' + ',';
                        });
                        unitsList += '}';
                        alert(unitsList);
                    }
                });
            },
```

But, this isn't working. The jqgrid DropDown column loaded with empty cell. Am I missing something? Is this the correct way to do? Please suggest if any alternate way to load the dropdown of jqgrid with server data with default value of that row being selected. Thanks.

Note:I'm using Jquery jqgrid v4.4.4 Visual Studio

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, it's important to understand when you should use `formatter: 'select'`, which you currently use. It's required if you want to fill the grid with id information in `UnitID`, but you need to display *the text*, which correspond the ids. For example, the JSON data, which you get from the server could contain the property `language`, with the content `"de"`, `"en"`, `"fr"` and so on, but you want to display in the column `"German"` instead of `"de"`, `"English"` instead of `"en"` and `"French"` instead of `"fr"`. In the case you should define

```
formatter: 'select', editoptions: { value: 'de:German;en:English;fr:French' },
editable: true, edittype: 'select'
```

If you *really need* to use `formatter: 'select'`, and you need to load the `editoptions.value` via Ajax from the server, then the `editoptions.value` have to be set *before* the main data of the grid returned from `url` will be processed. In the case, I would recommend you to *extend* the standard data returned from `url` with the data required for the `editoptions.value`. One can use `beforeProcessing` callback (which is supported even in the retro version 4.4.4, which you use) and to set `editoptions.value` dynamically with respect of `setColProp` method. See [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19427444/315935) for more details and the code example.

If you *don't need to use `formatter: 'select'`* (if ids and the values, used in select, are the same), then you can change the format of data returned from `GetUnit` action to the serialized array:

```
["Unit1", "Unit2", "Unit2/3"]
```

and to use `dataUrl` with `buildSelect` properties of `editoptions` instead of `value`. The value of `dataUrl` should be URL of `GetUnit` action, which return array of strings with all utits. The callback `buildSelect` should convert the JSON array to HTML fragment, which represent `<select>` with all the options. See [the old answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4102155/315935), for more implementation details and code examples.

Finally, you should fix `width: "200px"` to `width: 200`. The value of `width` property should be the number or the string which could be converted to the number. The usage of `px` or and other suffix is wrong. The next recommend fix would be removing `index: 'UnitID'` and all other `index` properties from `colModel`, if the value of `index` property is the same as the value of `name` property.

Comment: As always you are so helpful. Thanks for your feedback. I tried as you suggested, but still I am getting the empty cells for the dropdown of my inline jqgrid. Please find the UPDATED code and kindly suggest me. Thanks.

Comment: @Kavitha: Sorry, but you misunderstood my suggestions. You should **not** make any additional Ajax call inside of `beforeProcessing`. The main answer on `url` (used to fill of main data of the grid) should contain the information which provide currently `GetUnit`. Please reread carefully [the answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19427444/315935), which I referenced in my current answer on your question. Look at the `colModelOptions` part in the JSON response and to the corresponding C# code.

Comment: You are Awesome. Thanks a lot. Its working perfect. Your comments are so helpful.